# 'Subiecit' meaning in Ovid Metamorphoses III 167?

Tags: grammar-choice, grammar-identification, ovidius, metamorphoses

Here is a line in Ovid which I find confusing:

> quo postquam subiit, nympharum tradidit uni
>   armigerae iaculum pharetramque arcusque retentos,
>   **altera depositae subiecit bracchia pallae,**
>   vincla duae pedibus demunt;

It is translated as

*On this day, having come to the grotto,
she gives to the keeping of her armour-bearer among her nymphs her hunting spear, her quiver, and her unstrung bow; another takes on her arm the robe she has laid by; two unbind her sandals from her feet.* (F.J.Miller)

So who is the subject, Diana or nymph? 'Depositae pallae' is I think, dative — laid aside robe; If 'Altera' is in nominative then it would mean a nymph, so the subject would be that nymph; 'bracchia' (n. Pl) I thought to be in accusative — so if the subiecit (subicio) would mean to throw,construed with acc. and dat., then Diana would be the subject? 
Lewis & Short gives  under subicio the same line from Ovid, 'bracchia pallae' — it doesn't make any sense for me as it would be to throw, lay, place "arms to, on the robes" The opposite, "pallam bracchiis" would look more logical?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The subject is *altera [nympha]*:

> another [nymph] threw her arms under the cast-off robe

The verb *subicio* is normally used with a nominative (the thrower), an accusative (the thing thrown), and a dative (that under which the accusative is thrown). In this case, arms are thrown under robes. You translate *subicio* as "throw to/on", but the prefix *sub-* normally indicates "under". As you say, it can be throwing, laying, or placing.